# Swift -- UITextField is not showing keyboard and I cannot edit it

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am adding an UITextField to a UIWindow that is on top of another UIWindow, but I cannot edit the UITextField. Also, when I change from one UITextField to another I get the following warning `rejected resignFirstResponder when being removed from hierarchy`. I added part of the code. I added `inputNote.delegate = self` and the methods are called but nothing happens when I try to type. Thank you for your time and answers.

```
calc = UIWindow(frame: cFrame)
calc.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert
calc.rootViewController = UIViewController()
calc.makeKeyAndVisible()
calc.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

self.view.addSubview(calc)



panel = UIWindow(frame: pFrame)
panel.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert
panel.rootViewController = UIViewController()
panel.makeKeyAndVisible()

calc.addSubview(panel)



let inputNote = UITextField()
inputNote.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
inputNote.clearsOnBeginEditing = true
inputNote.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
inputNote.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 150, width: width - 5, height: 35)
inputNote.placeholder = "Note"

panel.addSubview(inputNote)
```

Comment: Are you running your project on Simulator or Physical device?

Comment: I'm running it in a simulator.

Comment: Do this: `Shift` + `Command` + `K` let me know!

Comment: It doesn't work, I already try all of that. I think it is something about the Windows I'm creating.

Comment: did you ever solve that? it's surely a problem with not using a storyboard and setting the window as root. I am currently struggling with this

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to enable the UITextField -
inputNote.isEnabled = true